# add length to a line that passes through 2 points and get the new end point

Tags: java, opengl, geometry, lwjgl, collision

i have been working with lwjgl and also j3d for the geometry part. i am still working on the collision. what i have so far witht he collision is working decently but there are 2 problems. to sum up my current way of colliding, it tests if the previous coordinate and current coordinate go through a triangle(what things are rendered as) and then it finds the point on the triangle that it just intersected that is closest to your current coordinate and makes you go there. it also makes your y coordinate go up by .001.
this workd descent but going up .001 is bad becuase if you go to a triangle that is at a 90* angle going updards you can go left to rigth but you cant back up out of it, almost as if you are stuck in it.
here is a drawing of how it works on imgur

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpweo.png

from here i want to add say .001 to the length between the current coordinate and the closest point (i already know these points) and get the new current point.

btw prev is where the person was at before they moved to the cur point and then it tests to see if those 2 points intersect a triangle and then i get the closest point to the prev if it does which is defined as closest in the picture. i can already calculate for all of those points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to add .001 to move away from the triangle. If that is the case then you need a vector of length 0.001 perpendicular to the triangle. In case of a triangle this is usually called the "normal". If you already have a normal for the triangle, then multiply that by .001 and add that. If you don't have a normal yet you can calculate it using cross product (you can Google the details of what a cross product is), something like this, from the vertices of the triangle:

```
Vector3 perpendicular = crossProduct(vertex3.pos - vertex1.pos, vertex2.pos - vertex1.pos);
Vector3 normal = perpendicular / length(normal);
Vector3 offset = normal * 0.001f;
```